# angularjs select required not working ng-options

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I am trying to ensure a user selects a value from a select box before submitting the form. 
This works correctly with static options; it however fails when populating the options via a model using ng-options

`Example`http://plnkr.co/edit/wRqSCNskLo5c48jy4nQf

I am using AngularJS 1.2.9

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't it because you didn't add any <option></option> ? See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JzLfC9PqcdMPUVCzpo4x?p=preview)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In your example changing the data bound select to the following fixes the required directive. I'm not sure why exactly.

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue1" ng-options="opt for opt in ['Mazda2','Maxda3']" required>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's the '<option></option>' tags that make it works

Answer (score 3):

You can also try ng-required="true" (it works on the latest AngularJS, not sure for 1.2.x).

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue1" ng-options="opt for opt in ['','Mazda2','Maxda3']" ng-required="true"></select>
```