# Why doesn't a required select prevent ng-submit?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

When a select is required in am html5 form and nothing is selected all the appropriate styling hooks seem to work and the field is considered invalid, but ng-submit still allows the form to attempt the submit.

Why does this happen and can I prevent submission if nothing is selected (preferably without controller logic)?

Below is a minimal example with some styling to make it obvious validation is invalid:

```js
angular.module('app', []).run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.options = ['1', '2', '3'];
  $rootScope.attempt = function() {
    alert('Attempted with ', $rootScope.selected)
  }
});
```

```css
.form-control.ng-invalid {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <p>Selected: {{selected}}</p>
  <form ng-submit="attempt()" class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="e for e in options" required></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<option></option>` in the `<select>` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24922101/541059) suggests

Comment: That tells me how to circumvent this really well and I am marking it as the answer for now, but I still really want to know why this works (so I can avoid making similar mistakes elsewhere). The answer in the link your provided doesn't explain either.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say it is Angular's problem. The `required` directive must look at `<select>`'s initial state. It would be empty, so it may affect the validation. This is total speculation, don't quote me on this.

You could try to set a default value for `$scope.selected` at the start of the controller.